# How to customize .jar file name

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, netbeans-8

How can I customize the name of the built jar file? I want its name to be other than the default value which is the project name. I don't want to change the project name. Let's say for example i want the jar file name to be (today's date_name).jar

Comment: are you using maven?

Comment: I am using Ant to build the project

Comment: Be clear about what you're asking.The default value in NetBeans is the project name, not the class name, and you can change it via the project properties.

Comment: My bad i meant project name... I've changed it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using NetBeans with default JAVA ANT Project, you can edit `project.properties` file in `nbproject`-folder.
search for (and change):
**dist.jar=${dist.dir}/MyNewFancyJARName.jar**

**NOTE:**
Your changes may be lost/overriden, when you change project-settings via NetBeans-GUI (because it may generate a new properties file).

**NOTE 2:**
**Maybe** there is another way to make this change more persistent.
Look for `private.properties` in folder: `nbproject/private`

Cheers!